# Copy Paste file to upload using Ajax Control toolkit AjaxFileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have implemented ASP.Net AjaxControlToolkit `AjaxFileupload` control to upload files in my ASP.Net web application.

It works fine,it uploads file by browsing,by drag and drop.

How can I let users to upload file by 'Copy and Paste' using this control.

Can this be done?

Please suggest if there is a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the clipboard when someone pastes something on your page but that doesn't give you access to the file in the file system.

If you want to be able to upload a file by Copy & Paste you have other solutions like flash, Java applet or ActiveX control. You can look into this answer for further information:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8481420/1124690